# Add dynamic HTML content to page with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dynamic-content

A database is giving me several divs to add to the DOM.

These `<divs>` have classes and onclick events already generated by the database.

I tried using jQuery and javascript by itself. The problem I'm getting with both is a conflict in quotes. When declaring the var -- or if I do `.html('dynamicinfo')` or `innerhtml('dynamicinfo')` -- I'm using the `'` character already at begining and end, so when the onclick syntax uses the `'` character as well... things stop working....

Any ideas on how to make this work?

**The jQuery looks something like this. (Note that the info variable in production use contains many divs, each with a different link)**

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
            var info = $('<div class="mainFixedButton mr2 mc3 mainDynamicButtons" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">From $399.99</div>');
            $("#number_pad").remove();
            $("#mainDynamicButtonContainer").html(info);
         });

<body>

    <div id="main_buttons">
        <div class="mainButtonContainer">
            <div id="mainDynamicButtonContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the quotes:

```
var info = $('<div ... onclick="window.location=\'http://www.google.com\'">From $399.99</div>');
```